# how to convert mongoDB Oplog file into actual query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-oplog

I want to convert the MongoDB local Oplog file into an actual real query so I can execute that query and get the exact copy database.
Is there any package, file, build-in tools, or script for it?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to get the exact query from the oplog entry because MongoDB doesn't save the query.

The oplog has an entry for each atomic modification performed. Multi-inserts/updates/deletes performed on the mongo instance using a single query are converted to multiple entries and written to the oplog collection. For example, if we insert 10,000 documents using `Bulk.insert()`, 10,000 new entries will be created in the oplog collection. Now the same can also be done by firing 10,000 `Collection.insertOne()` queries. The oplog entries would look identical! There is no way to tell which one actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but that is impossible.

The reason is that, that opLog doesn't have queries. OpLog includes only changes (add, update, delete) to data, and it's there for replication and redo.

To get an exact copy of DB, it's called "replication", and that is of course supported by the system.

To "replicate" changes to f.ex. one DB or collection, you can use https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/.

Comment: thanks for the answer yes I understand replica things but my requirement is I will build a new database that should not connect with this database as a replica set but I want the same data so for that I have to write a script that will loop at oplog file and execute query so being copy of original file for example if oplog transaction have "d" means it delete query so i will execute delete query with object_id which i will get in oplog if it is "u" means it is update so i will execute update query with all changes i will get from oplog file

Comment: Check my edit to the answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the query from the Oplogs. Oplog defines multiple op types, for instance op: "i","u", "d" etc, are for insert, update, delete. For these types, check the "o"/"o2" fields which have corresponding data and filters.
Now based on the op types call the corresponding driver APIs db.collection.insert()/update()/delete().